# How to bind both IPv4 and IPv6 source address to Python socket?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, ipv6

I wish to create a TCP server using sockets, that binds to both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

Is there a way to do it without creating 2 sockets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called "dual-stack", or an IPv4 + IPv6 dual-stack socket.

Since Python 3.8, you're able to easily do so using [`socket.create_server()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.create_server).

Setting the parameter `dualstack_ipv6=True` will allow you, on supported systems, to listen on both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses using the same socket.

If you wish to check if your system supports dual-stack sockets, use `socket.has_dualstack_ipv6()`.

Code example from the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.create_server):

> ```
> import socket
>
> addr = ("", 8080)  # all interfaces, port 8080
> if socket.has_dualstack_ipv6():
>     s = socket.create_server(addr, family=socket.AF_INET6, dualstack_ipv6=True)
> else:
>     s = socket.create_server(addr)
> ```

Comment: Note: `socket.create_server()` creates a TCP socket and cannot be used for UDP